# Selecting adjacent Bootstrap classes in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu which has a nice little arrow on the top border (courtesy of *cssarrowsplease*).

I also have a submenu within the main dropdown menu, however this secondary menu that opens also has that same little arrow because the arrow styling is tied to the `.dropdown-menu` class.

While I want the little arrow on the **main** dropdown, I do not want it displayed on the subsequent submenu's.

I tried to get around this issue by using the `+` CSS selector and adding a `.maindd` class to the first, main dropdown menu:

```
 <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">travel <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="maindd dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="tanzania.html" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">Tanzania </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="menu-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Arusha</a></li>
                  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Northern Circuit</a></li>
              </ul>
         </li>
```

My plan was then to use `.maindd + .dropdown-menu` in the CSS so that the arrow code only runs on the dropdown menu **immediately** after the `.maindd` class.

Unfortunately this is not working and the arrow has completely vanished :(
Any ideas why?

**EDIT ---** Here is link so you can check it out http://stackoverflowquestion.bss.design/

Comment: can't reproduce the issue, please show a MVCE

Comment: Have added a link @dippas

Comment: Please include all relevant code here, including your CSS.

Comment: `EDIT --- Here is link so you can check it out http://stackoverflowquestion.bss.design/` —  Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin but the external resource is still there and isn't fixed?

Comment: @DDiran — It's survived a whole 50 minutes! Wow! Will it still be there in 5 years time?